# Reading/storing a text file in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a text file in the following format and store it (java).
The format of the text file is like this:

```
1111
1010
1100
1000
```

It's a Hadamard matrix as you can tell. I'm very new to java and can't figure out how to accomplish this. I want to be able to perform computations on the matrix.

Can someone help me with this

Comment: Start with [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: Try these tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tough. you should learn File Handling in java. there is plenty of tutorials over internet. Use Google. I am posting here the code as required. if this helpful vote me up as i needed and accept it as answer. (courtesy: http://www.mkyong.com/)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileReaderWriter {

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Reader();
    Writer();
}
static void Reader(){
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\matrix.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
static void Writer(){
    try {

        String content = "1010\n1111\n0000\n0101\n";
        System.out.println("Writing ... \n"+content);
        File file = new File("D:\\matrix.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```